# Laravel restful routes contain parameters

Tags: laravel, routes

In my Laravel routes file (web.php), i have the following route.

```
Route::resource('notifications/{section_id}', 'NotificationController', ['as' => 'notifications']);
```

I then have a blade template which opens a form like so

```
{!! Form::model($qList,['route' => ['notifications.store']]) !!}
```

However, this line generates an error saying `Route [notifications.store] not defined.`

Running `php artisan route:list` I can see that the route name is `notifications.{section_id}.store`. i.e. `{section_id}` is included in the route name. Is this my problem?  The parameter doesn't seem to be appearing for any of my other routes and I do have a `store` method in my NotificationController

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove the {section_id} parameter and route:list again.

Comment: That does work and shows the correct route, but I need to pass a parameter to my controller. The {section_id} is required

Comment: Dump the $request->input('section_id') inside the store method. Don't forget to add Request $request as parameter in the method implementation

Comment: How is the store route looking now? Paste it from the route:list output.

Comment: But that is my problem. I do have a store method in my NotificationsController, but the error message is saying the method doesn't exist

Comment: Can you please paste the error, not the full stack but the main one. As I see your error is saying that the route is not defined not the method inside the controller

Comment: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314:

Comment: Route [notifications.store] not defined. (View: C:\***\***\***\notifications.blade.php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142734/discussion-between-calin-blaga-and-typhoon101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this, writing the full route name and passing the section_id parameter in the route array:

```
Form::model($qList,['route' => ['notifications.{section_id}.store', $section_id]])
```

then, the form submit url will become (assuming 99 as your section id)

```
<form method="POST" action="http://laravel5.dev/notifications/99" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="...">
```

Moreover, you can choose to force route names on your RESTful routes with the 'names' parameter, like this:

```
Route::resource('notifications/{section_id}', 'TestController', ['as' => 'notifications', 'names' => ['store' => 'notifications.store']]);
```

then, with `php artisan route:list` you will see

```
| Domain | Method                         | URI                                            | Name                                     | Action                                      | Middleware   |
+--------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | POST                           | notifications/{section_id}                     | notifications.store                      | App\Http\Controllers\TestController@store   | web          |
```

Comment: This steered me in the right direction. Thanks for your help